# Regex quotation marks C#

Tags: c#, regex

Code:

```
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(lmn, @"Text(.+*?)(")", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

I do not get how I can use " The problem is matching with C# "

Answer (score 1):

Use double double quotes and you must change `.+*?` to `.+?`

```
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(lmn, @"Text(.+?)("")", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: `@` is there then is it needed for `""` to represent a `"`?

Comment: @un-lucky Yes; because "\" has no meaning inside such. Search for 'verbatim string literal' for the details.